# Android Studio Activity keeps Crashing

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

Background: my activities are connected to each other through buttons (imagebuttons and buttons). they should launch a new activity every time they are clicked.

But my app keeps crashing after every 3 or so clicks. a message saying "Unfortunately THEAPP5 has topped". it will then relaunch that specific page at which point the button on that page will start working and connect to the next activity. however to only then repeat the issue on a different activity.

I have checked the button names/types/ID's etc. just can't figure out why this is happening. **I'm a beginner with Android Studio.**

I have attached the complete code from one activity. all activities have the same basic code.

```
package com.example.d.myluxuryapp5;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class AutoLux extends Activity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_lux);

    ImageButton AutoLuxury = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.luxuryUserBtn);

    AutoLuxury.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LuxMM.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}}
```

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/luxury_background"
tools:context="com.example.d.myluxuryapp5.AutoLux">


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/luxuryUserBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/luxury_user_button"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/otherUserBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/other_user_button"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your help

### LOGCAT for the moment the app crashes + relaunches

```
    03-07 10:43:34.081 3818-3818/com.example.d.myluxuryapp5 E/AndroidRuntime:FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.d.myluxuryapp5, PID: 3818
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.d.myluxuryapp5/com.example.d.myluxuryapp5.OptOne}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
    at com.example.d.myluxuryapp5.OptOne.onCreate(OptOne.java:23)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
    at com.example.d.myluxuryapp5.OptOne.onCreate(OptOne.java:23) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
    at com.example.d.myluxuryapp5.OptOne.onCreate(OptOne.java:23) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1172244 byte allocation with 197464 free bytes and 192KB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3948)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:677)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:671)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:667)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
    at com.example.d.myluxuryapp5.OptOne.onCreate(OptOne.java:23) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Why aren't you including the stack trace from logcat?

Comment: use `getApplicationContext()` instead `getContext()`

Comment: Please share your source in google drive or any other place and I'll check that.

Answer (score 2):

Use your activity instance instead of your view's one when creating the instance. Do it as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AutoLux.this, LuxMM.class);
```

Comment: i have done as you stated but had no luck. my app still continues to crash and reload, then work until the next activity.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

- I create the same project about what you post, and any exception,
  like yours, show up. May be some IDE problems, try to close it, open
  it and click on "clean project"
- Also try Change it in your styles file

  ...

correct the intent, also add the `fisnish()`, this is to end the current activty but, if you want to go back from the LuxMM to AutoLux (or anyone), use another intent to navigate between them. Don't forget to add the permission to the manifest.

```
AutoLuxury.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(AutoLux.this, LuxMM.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: i have done as you stated but had no luck. my app still continues to crash and reload, then work until the next activity. i would like to add the feature to go back in the app however i would prefer to make it work completely when moving forward in activities first.

Comment: checking the logcat, are different ways or causes, in this case, check, i'll update some solutions, also may be the button's dimensions..

Comment: iv cleaned my project as you stated, also updated all files and IDE. with no luck. it's still crashing. would it be possible to send you my entire app to check the problem.    i have also updated the LogCat

Comment: @DMan if it's ok with you, upload your code to mega or something like that, share here the link and i check it  and update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use [getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29) instead [getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29)

```
AutoLuxury.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LuxMM.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: still the same issue.

Comment: I saw this on log cat error. `Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class <unknown>`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly your problem I tried all above answers but didn't work , I got rid of problem by my self finally
your problem is your new activity layout.xml  (too maybe graphical)
that`s why after 2or 3time it crashes 
    have a good time.